# Not able to open sonar server on the web browser

Tags: sonarqube

I am using open suse 12.2.I downloaded sonar 3.4 and configured it.From terminal,I started the sonar server.But when I try to open it from the browser,I am getting an error 503.Following is the contents of my log.

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/01/03 16:55:52 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:53 | 2013-01-03 16:55:53.055:INFO::Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:53 | 2013-01-03 16:55:53.055:INFO::Shutdown hook executing
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:53 | 2013-01-03 16:55:53.064:INFO::Graceful shutdown org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@22994311{/,file:/home/tom/sonar-3.4/war/sonar-server}
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:54 | 2013-01-03 16:55:54.064:INFO::Stopped SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:54 | 2013-01-03 16:55:54.069:INFO::Shutdown hook complete
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | 2013-01-03 16:55:55.813:INFO::Logging to org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger@76663cdf via org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:55 | 2013-01-03 16:55:55.856:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 2013-01-03 16:55:56.034:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,437 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,442 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,443 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,446 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Setting up default configuration.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,538 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,564 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil@d0a861a - Failed to get local hostname java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-svq9: linux-svq9: Name or service not known
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-svq9: linux-svq9: Name or service not known
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.getLocalHostName(ContextUtil.java:30)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.addHostNameAsProperty(ContextUtil.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction.begin(ConfigurationAction.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:277)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:149)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:131)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:148)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:134)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:97)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.sonar.core.config.Logback.configure(Logback.java:71)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.sonar.core.config.Logback.configure(Logback.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.configureLogback(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:45)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:32)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:74)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:49)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-svq9: Name or service not known
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 |   at  ... 31 common frames omitted
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,566 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SONAR_FILE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,607 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@77291e95 - No compression will be used
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SONAR_FILE] - Active log file name: /home/tom/sonar-3.4/logs/sonar.log
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SONAR_FILE] - File property is set to [/home/tom/sonar-3.4/logs/sonar.log]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [PROFILING_FILE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,627 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@2c970551 - No compression will be used
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[PROFILING_FILE] - Active log file name: /home/tom/sonar-3.4/logs/profiling.log
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[PROFILING_FILE] - File property is set to [/home/tom/sonar-3.4/logs/profiling.log]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [rails] to false
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - rails level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SONAR_FILE] to Logger[rails]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.cache.ReadWriteCache level set to ERROR
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.SQL level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.apache.ibatis level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - java.sql level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - java.sql.ResultSet level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.sonar.MEASURE_FILTER level set to WARN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to INFO
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SONAR_FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 16:55:56,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@6ede1fb5 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:56 | 
2013.01.03 16:55:56 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  Sonar Server / 3.4 / 9db1dffb31df6def5b2d28d903fa1a7de6a725a3
2013.01.03 16:55:58 INFO  o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase  Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2013.01.03 16:55:58 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  Unable to start database
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to start database
    at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabase.start(EmbeddedDatabase.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:72) ~[sonar-plugin-api-3.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:186) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:129) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:74) [sonar-application-3.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:49) [sonar-application-3.4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-svq9: linux-svq9: Name or service not known" [90028-167]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:273) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:263) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.getURL(TcpServer.java:193) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    at org.h2.tools.Server.start(Server.java:456) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabase.start(EmbeddedDatabase.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-svq9: linux-svq9: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:261) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-svq9: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 | 2013-01-03 16:55:58.831:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@6bf58923{/,file:/home/tom/sonar-3.4/war/sonar-server}
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 | org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to start database
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabase.start(EmbeddedDatabase.java:75)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:41)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:186)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:129)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:74)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:49)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/01/03 16:55:58 | 2013-01-03 16:55:58.848:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9000
```

My configuration file is as follows

## --------------------------------------------------------

```
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters
# see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# To use an environment variable, use the following syntax :  ${env:NAME_OF_ENV_VARIABLE}
# For example :
#   sonar.jdbc.url: ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
#
#
# See also the file conf/wrapper.conf for JVM advanced settings
#---------------------------------------------------------


#---------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SETTINGS - STANDALONE MODE ONLY
# These settings are ignored when the war file is deployed to a JEE server.
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Listen host/port and context path (for example / or /sonar). Default values are 0.0.0.0:9000/.
sonar.web.host:                           127.0.0.1
sonar.web.port:                           9000
sonar.web.context:                        /

# Log HTTP requests. Deactivated by default.
#sonar.web.jettyRequestLogs: ../../logs/jetty-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log
#sonar.web.jetty.threads.min:              5
#sonar.web.jetty.threads.max:              50
#sonar.web.jetty.threads.low:              10

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT : the embedded database H2 is used by default. 
# It is recommended for tests only. Please use an external database
# for production environment (MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql, SQLServer)
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#----- Credentials
# Permissions to create tables and indexes must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonar

#----- Embedded database H2
# Note : it does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# sonar server and the maven plugin must be executed on the same host.
  
# Comment the following line to deactivate the default embedded database.
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.h2.Driver

# directory containing H2 database files. By default it's the /data directory in the sonar installation.
sonar.embeddedDatabase.dataDir:
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port:               9092


#----- MySQL 5.x/6.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line to use MySQL
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# To connect to Oracle database :
#
# - It's recommended to use the latest version of the JDBC driver (either ojdbc6.jar for Java 6 or ojdbc5.jar for Java 5).
#   Download it in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html
# - Copy the driver to the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line :
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# Uncomment the following property if the Oracle account has permissions to access multiple schemas,
# for example sonar schemas with different versions. In that case, use the same property during project analysis
# (-Dsonar.jdbc.schema=<schema>)
# The schema is case-sensitive.
#sonar.jdbc.schema:                         sonar


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following property to use PostgreSQL
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.postgresql.Driver

# Uncomment the following property if the PostgreSQL account has permissions to access multiple schemas,
# for example sonar schemas with different versions. In that case, use the same property during project analysis
# (-Dsonar.jdbc.schema=<schema>)
#sonar.jdbc.schema:                         public


#----- Microsoft SQLServer
# The Jtds open source driver is available in extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql. More details on http://jtds.sourceforge.net
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver


#----- Connection pool settings
sonar.jdbc.maxActive:                      20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle:                        5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle:                        2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait:                        5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis:     600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis:  30000


#---------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER
#---------------------------------------------------------

# The Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is activated by default:
#sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
#http.proxyHost=
#http.proxyPort=

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=

#---------------------------------------------------------
# NOTIFICATIONS
#---------------------------------------------------------

# Delay (in seconds) between processing of notification queue
sonar.notifications.delay=60
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what OS you are deployed on, but on RHEL 6.7 adding the host name to /etc/hosts fixed this for us.

Comment: Worked well on archlinux also !

Answer (score 0):

Its becoz of DB initialization problem ar localhost:
 
You should use your DB server and web server on same url...
your jdbc.url should be same as which you have configured in sonar server properties if it is not in your localhost.